# Should questions asking about the existence of a feature on a website that turns out not to exist be systemically closed or left open?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I asked https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170373/18147. The answer seems to be no,  it's not possible. One moderator closed the question with the reason:

> I closed this question because it's a feature request that should be addressed to the web app developer.[Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n)**♦** [Apr 29 at 7:00](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/170373/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-when-adding-files-to-an-existing-ar#comment158200_170373)

Should questions asking about the existence of a feature that turns out not to exist be systemically closed or left open?

---

Other examples of questions asking about the existence of a feature that seems not to exist. I see that typically the questions are left open (I didn't select them based on whether they were still open):

- [Is it possible to add icons to individual reports in a report module in CommCare?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104367/18147)
- [How do I view messages in a discussion group on a per-message basis (Facebook)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107228/18147)
- [Change Pin Icons in Bing Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4808/18147)
- [How can I add a new recipient to a Facebook message?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6977/18147)
- [Is it possible to view change history of a Google shared calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11720/18147)
- [How do I stop Facebook from suggesting my friends join my closed Facebook groups?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107505/18147)
- [Can I stop all comments on Facebook posts on a page I manage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121327/18147)
- [Sort GitHub issues by title](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/131880/18147)
- [Is editing part of Youtube audio in a video possible via the Youtube editor?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148303/18147)
- [Collapsible containers overlap when expanding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/151486/18147)
- [How can I assign different colors to comments and nested comments in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50294/18147)
- [Sorting on a web-published Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40795/18147)
- [Shortcut key to delete single mail in a conversation in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4673/18147)
- [How to set timezone of Google Groups?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8446/18147)
- [Change RSS name for Yahoo pipe](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21643/18147)
- [How to find out if I have been removed from a friend's Yahoo! Messenger's contact list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/15005/18147)
- [Is it possible to create index page on Tumblr?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18573/18147)
- [How to get the lat/lon coordinates along a road?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31453/18147)
- [In Mint.com, can we run any SQL like queries?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74084/18147)
- [Access "old" Google+ Hangout from web browser?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24032/18147)
- [How can I create a online collaborative document where I only allow certain users to edit certain sections?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39076/18147)

Answer (score 3):

Asking about the existence of a feature on a website that turns out not to exist shouldn't be a reason to close the question. Rationale:

1. The OP doesn't know ahead of time if the feature exists (since they are asking the question).
2. The feature may be introduced later.
3. The feature may not be built-in but workarounds may exist.

Comment: Please add an [argument map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_map).

Comment: @Rubén I listed three arguments on why asking about the existence of a feature on a website that turns out not to exist shouldn't be a reason to close the question. How would an argument improve that answer?

Comment: Argument maps help to have better discussions and avoid going in circles and other usual problems when there are reasons and objections for something. They are recommended when discussing wicked problems. Later I will add more about this.