# Why do mods sometimes decide not to follow the community consensus when deciding to keep questions closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, moderation

For example, in the following meta questions, the community consensus is to reopen the corresponding main site questions:

1. In the meta question [Why was my question on how to disable "small caps" in one's text in PowerPoint 365 closed as "esoteric" by a mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5088/18147), the community consensus is to reopen the question    [How can I disable "small caps" in my text in PowerPoint 365 on the web?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171637/18147) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20230812045619/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171637/how-can-i-disable-small-caps-in-my-text-in-powerpoint-365-on-the-web), [mirror 2](https://archive.is/SDlrW), [mirror 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGU9Q.jpg)) (it's been reopened since then).
2. In the meta question [In the context of webapps, how can one assess whether a question is a customer service-related question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5203/18147), the community consensus is to reopen the questions [How to make a Reddit account without "instant shadowban"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173320/18147) (it's been reopened since then) and [Showing pictures on a map in the web version of Google Photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173342/18147)
3. In the meta question [Why was my question on listing all mails in Outlook closed by a moderator as "needs details or clarity"?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5073/18147), the community consensus is to reopen the question [How can I see the list of all mails I received, regardless of which folder they are located in, in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?](https://web.archive.org/web/20230705042553/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171094/how-can-i-see-the-list-of-all-mails-i-received-regardless-of-which-folder-they) (it's been reopened since then).
4. In the meta question [Should questions asking about the existence of a feature on a website that turns out not to exist be systemically closed or left open?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5030/18147), the community consensus is to reopen the question [How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166848/18147) (it's been reopened since then).
5. In the meta question [Why was this question on setting up automatic alerts for new YouTube videos matching keywords closed by a moderator?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5092/18147), the community consensus is to reopen the question [Can I setup automatic alerts for new YouTube videos that match keywords?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171660/18147) (it's been reopened since then).

However, the mods who closed the questions decided to keep these questions closed, thereby going against the community consensus.

Why did mods decide to go against the community consensus by leaving these questions closed?

Comment: There seems to be a pattern here…

Comment: @galacticninja And the list is far from exhaustive. You're welcome to add more examples btw.

Comment: I'm now seeing a bunch more stuff reopened by Blindspots, some of which happened quickly after I pushed for reopening (i.e., flags and edits). Some of these might have had flags from other users pending for longer though.

Comment: There are a bunch of questions on this list that were deleted by Roomba, which are tricky to handle. Do you know if they would be auto-deleted even if they were reopened?

Comment: @Laurel  [https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171637/18147](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171637/18147) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20230812045619/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171637/how-can-i-disable-small-caps-in-my-text-in-powerpoint-365-on-the-web), [mirror 2](https://archive.is/SDlrW), [mirror 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGU9Q.jpg))  would not get auto-deleted if it is reopened.

Comment: @Laurel [How can I see the list of all mails I received, regardless of which folder they are located in, in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?](https://web.archive.org/web/20230705042553/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171094/how-can-i-see-the-list-of-all-mails-i-received-regardless-of-which-folder-they) would be autodeleted if left as such, but I'd assume reopeners would upvote and I would add an answer (since I now know the answer), so in practice in won't be autodeleted.

Comment: @Laurel FYI [How can I view the list of the questions that were the most recently reopened on a given SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396024/178179)

Comment: Are you sure this is really a request for information about "why"?  Or is this actually a complaint and request for action, rather than a request for information?  If moderators gave you reasons why would you  consider that a satisfactory answer to this post, or would you then debate the matter with them in this post?  If this is actually a complaint or a request to re-open the questions, please be explicit and direct about the actual intent.